# NetSuite: Scripting assembly builds to only withdraw inventory when approved

Tags: javascript, netsuite, inventory, suitescript

I'm trying to write a script that will prevent finished goods from being withdrawn from inventory if the assembly build is awaiting approval. This is the first script I've ever done and first time ever using Javascript so I apologize if what I have so far makes no sense (and if I sound dumb). The script checks if the record is an assembly build that is being created or edited then creates a temporary field, "quantity pending". When saved, if approval status is "awaiting approval", the script assigns the value of quantity pending to the value in Quantity to Build, then Quantity to Build is set to 0 and the record is submitted. If the approval status is approved, Quantity to Build is set to the value stored in quantity pending, and quantity pending is set to 0, the record is then submitted. Again I apologize if this makes no sense.

I tried using the Script Debugger but I don't think my code works. Could someone point out where I went wrong or if I'm on the right track?

Here is what I have so far. If anyone has done something like this or knows of a better approach, I'm all ears.

```
function commitIfApproved() {
    var cR = nlapiGetOldRecord();       
    var recordId = cR.nlapiGetRecordID();       
    var recordType = cR.nlapiGetRecordType();       
    if (recordId == 'assemblybuild') {      
        if(recordType = 'create' || 'edit') {       
            var approvalstatus = cR.nlapiGetFieldValue('approval status');      
            var quantityPending = cR.nlapiGetFieldValue('quantity to build - pending');     
            if (approvalstatus == "Awaiting Approval") {    
                cR.nlapiSetFieldValue('quantity to build', '0');        
                cR.nlapiSetFieldValue('quantity to build - pending', quantityPending);      
                cR.nlapiSubmitRecord();     
                alert("Finished goods will not be taken from inventory until this assembly build is approved.");
            }
            if (approvalstatus == "Approved") {     
                cR.nlapiSetFieldValue('quantity to build', quantityPending);    
                cR.nlapiSetFieldValue('quantity to build - pending', '0');      
                cR.nlapiSubmitRecord();     
                alert("This assembly build has been approved. Finished goods have been subtracted from inventory.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First error I see is with your `recordId` comparison. You will want to change your `if` statement that compares to `assemblybuild` to use `recordType` instead of `recordId`.

Second is with your method calls in your `recordId` and `recordType` assignments. `nlapiGetRecordId()` and `nlapiGetRecordType()` are global static methods. The instance methods are `getRecordType()` and `getId()`. The same is true for all of your calls to `setFieldValue`. See the Help article titled *nlobjRecord* for details on the record object's API.

`var recordId = nlapiGetRecordId(); // alternatively, cr.getId()
var recordType = nlapiGetRecordType(); // alternatively, cr.getRecordType();`

Lastly, your field IDs are all wrong. `'quantity to build'` is not a real ID. You will want to check the Records Browser in the Eclipse IDE (Help > NetSuite Records Browser) for the page on Assembly Build records to see all of the fields and their respective IDs.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding my mistakes and explaining it all very clearly! I haven't made any adjustments to my code so far but I'll let you know if it works! For some reason it's so difficult to find good sources on NetSuite articles and help.